# Find items in a string collection which contain another string

Tags: c#, collections

I have a collection which has strings in it.
Such as:

```
"iphone x sadasd"
"IPHONE X s325g"
"Another string"
```

I am adding these strings in a listbox, but not all of them.

I want to add strings into a listbox based on the text entered in a textbox. e.g I might enter the text "iphone x "

So far I have tried:

```
if(collection.Contains(textBox1.Text));
{
    listbox1.items.Add(//string that contains texbox1.text)
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to use `Where` ?

Comment: i got my answer. Why everyone is giving me down votes ?

Comment: Because your question is poorly researched, unclear, unlikely to help others, and is a list of your demands rather than a question.

Answer (score 2):

Use [AddRange Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z018s5az(v=vs.110).aspx) with [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
listbox1.Items.AddRange(collection.Where(x => x.Contains(textBox1.Text));
```

Comment: @bkirknk if one of the answers posted answered your question please select it as such, thanks.

Comment: You might also want to do some case checking and (possibly) trimming of the text entered in the text box.